# Toolbar doesn't show in android studio preview

Tags: android-studio

Android toolbar doesn't show in android studio,but it's shown on the device. I tracked so many topics but there is no specific solution.I create a new project on android and It's not shown anyway.Also it doesn't show my old projects.

[image: empty1.png]

[image: empty2.png]

device

Also I get those errors

**Render Problem**

Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

Failed to instantiate one or more classes

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.

But those problems deosn't show when I add "Base." inside to style apptheme.

What did I so far

1. Someone says it's about "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
   So use "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1" but it's didn't work.Also I tried with alpha3.
2. I change apptheme on style.xml I tried "NoActionBar","Dark.ActionBar" and so many others.But nothing change.
3. Clear cache but it's didn't work.
4. I add ".Base" inside to style.xml (apptheme).

MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.parala"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Gradle2

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.parala">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Style

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="koko" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">40dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No AndroidX, right?

Comment: No,I use normal libraries.

Comment: You use old support libraries?

Comment: I'm using v28 for all design libraries.Now I clean and re-setup my computer.I'll try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not the completely right answer.But it's pratic for any other case.Down your gradle v27.This way the toolbar appears on layout manager, and upgrade again to v28 just before publishing your project.